# Set_Rules Error in Linux : Undefined property: Welcome::$input

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

I am learning codeigniter. I am watching a course videos in udemy.The last video was about the form validation. I wrote the codes in the video. But it is not working in ubuntu. Codes only work on windows. I get an error when I try to use the set rules function. Codeigniter folder permissions are 755. Where is the problem ? **CODES ARE WORKING IN WINDOWS BUT NOT WORKING LINUX :)**

Welcome class :

```
 class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('form');

    }

    public function save(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Username', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'başarılı';
        }
    }

}
```

Form view :

```
<form action="<?=base_url("Welcome/save")?>" method="post">

    <input type="text" id="fname" name="name"><br>
    <button type="submit">Gönder</button>
</form>
```

Error image :

Sorry, click for error picture.

[Error :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn2NZ.png)

Comment: Strangely enough I've taken your code, ran it on my LAMP server (Kubuntu) and it works. I would have suggested it's a filename Case issue as it works on windows and not on linux but you are using out of the box Welcome... Basically I cannot get it to break; So something else is afoot here.

Comment: Have you tried to run the example from the CI 3 user guide?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question and removing the answer. Please do not use screenshots of your code and error messages. They are hard to read on mobile devices, cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image. Include Code/error messages as text in the question itself. Please respond to this comment by improving your question with edits, not comments. See [**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw yes i run the example. İf i use set_rules function it always get this error.

Comment: Is `echo $this->input->post("name");` working ?

Comment: @Dum no, again this error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, Input library is damaged. Replace the following file with an original one.

```
system/core/Input.php
```

Or try a fresh install.